# Fetching Apache Flink results using Springboot API

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, apache-flink

I have created a springboot code to use an API so that I can fetch the flink results when the user hits the endpoint.

`static Map<String, Long> finalList = new HashMap<String, Long>();`

Above is the class variable outside the main method. Within the main method, a datastream API for flink is used to fetch data from Kafka using KafkaSource class and perform the aggregations in flink. The datastream is being put into data_15min variable which is an object of DataStream<Map<String, Long>>.

I used a map function to fetch the data from the datastream and put them into the above finalList object.

```
data_15min.map(new MapFunction<Map<String, Long>, Object>() {
                ObjectMapper objMapperNew = new ObjectMapper();
                @Override
                public Object map(Map<String, Long> value) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Value in map: " + value);
                    System.out.println("KeySet: " + value.keySet());
                    value.forEach((key, val) -> {

                        if(!dcListNew.contains(key)) {
                            dcListNew.add(key);
                            finalList.put(key, val);

                        } else {
                            finalList.replace(key, val);
                        }
                    });

                    System.out.println("DC List NEw inside: " + dcListNew);
                    System.out.println("Final List inside: " + objMapperNew.writeValueAsString(finalList));
                    return finalList;
                }
});
System.out.println("Final List: " + finalList);
```

On printing the finalList within the above map function I am getting the data as

`Final List inside: {"ABC": 2, "AXY": 10}`

Outside the map when I print, I still see it as:
`Final List: {}`

Can someone please help me so that this data is avialable outside the map method for me to send it to springboot api response?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason this does not work is becuse of concurrency, I assume that You are calling `execute()` on your environment there somewhere, so only after `execute()` finishes Your `finalList` has been populated with records.

Note that working like this isn't safe at all and quite probably will result in errors after short time. Overall, seems that the architecture of the solution is missing something like database where You would store Your results from Flink and then access the db from Spring.

Comment: Isn't it possible to directly snapshot the finalList at the specific moment I hit the spring boot endpoint? So when I hit the endpoint, it fetches the flink result at the moment. Is database or some storage needed?

Comment: Overall, If I understand correctly You want to expose this `finalList` through some HTTP api is that correct ?

Comment: Correct, whenever I hit the endpoint, the data within finalList at the specific moment should be sent via response of springboot API

Comment: There are tons of issues with doing that like above:
1. Race conditions (as the one You have hit).
2. There is no way to tell if all updates have been done or if You are just sending partially updated response
3. There is no state management since that's a global variable if Flink restarts progress is lost.
4. This is not scalable at all, You can't distribute load with Flink using above assumptions.

My reccomendation would be: either use some external state store or resign from Flink as it's not gonna be useful.

Comment: In case of not using a static variable in my code, how can go ahead store the same data {"ABC": 2, "AXY": 10} in a state so that I can use it later?

Comment: Use somekind of datastorage :)